# How can i make my jQuery function with .each() in it shorter?

Tags: jquery

My function:

```
    $('a[href$=".pdf"]').each(function () {
        var $linkText = $(this).text();
        $(this).attr('onclick', "_gaq.push(['_trackEvent','" + $linkText + "','click']);");
    });

    $('a[href$=".doc"]').each(function () {
        var $linkText = $(this).text();
        $(this).attr('onclick', "_gaq.push(['_trackEvent','" + $linkText + "','click']);");
    });
```

the parts are repetitive:

```
var $linkText = $(this).text();
        $(this).attr('onclick', "_gaq.push(['_trackEvent','" + $linkText + "','click']);");
```

How can i pull those parts into an outside function so that I'll have something like this ?:

```
$('a[href$=".xls"]').each(function (index, value) {            
        AddGoogleTracking(value);
    });

function AddGoogleTracking(value) {
    var $linkText = value.text();
    $(this).attr('onclick', "_gaq.push(['_trackEvent','" + $linkText + "','click']);");
}
```

Comment: Don't set `onclick` attributes with jQuery. Use event binding with [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on) instead

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could select both together:

```
$('a[href$=".pdf"], a[href$=".doc"]');
```

You can also simplify by adding the click handler directly, like this:

```
$('a[href$=".pdf"], a[href$=".doc"]').click(function() {
    _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', $(this).text(), 'click']);
});
```

It might be a good idea to simplify *further* by giving any link you want tracked a common class, so you can select them that way:

```
$('.track-link').click(...);
```

Comment: The comma-to-select-both syntax is easy to miss at a glance (especially if you often use longer selectors pretty often), so I'd definitely add the common class

Answer (score 0):

Don't add an `[onclick]` attribute, don't repeat a selector when the same function body applies to both.

Do use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on) to bind `click` events to the matched elements:

```
$('a[href$=".pdf"], a[href$=".doc"]').on('click', function () {
    window._gaq.push(['_trackEvent', $(this).text(), 'click']);
});
```